# Drupal 8: Template suggestion for form-element in a views exposed filter is not working

Tags: 8, theming

In Drupal 8 I am trying to add in a suggestion via hook_theme_suggestions_alter() like so:

```
function ua_sc_theme_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
  print '<!-- hook: ' . $hook . '-->';
  if (in_array($hook, ['input', 'form_element']) && $variables['element']['#attributes']['id'] == 'edit-keys') {
    $suggestions[] = $hook . '__custom';
  }
}
```

...and then I give my template a name of form-element__custom.html.twig and put it in my theme it doesn't get used an instead the default form-element.html.twig template is used. Any thoughts on what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, looks like I was too tired. The problem was that the template should be called form-element--custom.html.twig.

Notice the '--' (double dash) instead of the __ (double underscore).

I also ended up using the more specific hook alter:

```
hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter
```

...where HOOK for me was form_element.

Answer (score 1):

In your form add `'#theme' => 'input__custom'` to the input element. The 'input' is the theme implementation and '__custom' is the suggestion.

This hook is for global suggestions.

Comment: I am trying to theme an exposed view filter form element - so I would need to do that in an alter. Is there no other way?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using hook_form_alter or hook_form_FORM_ID_alter in this case.